# grid view i have to display the 3X3 matrix how to do that

Tags: java, android, gridview

grid view i have to display the 3X3 matrix how to do that.

input values are horizontal value and vertical value.

for example horizontal value is 3 and vertical value 3 then i have to diaplay to below format

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

for example horizontal value is 2 and vertical value 2 then i have to diaplay to below format

```
1 2
3 4
```

for example horizontal value is 3 and vertical value 2 then i have to diaplay to below format

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your condition use the following:

```
         setNumColumns(int)
```

This will set the no of columns at runtime.

```
   for example horizontal value is 3 and vertical value 3 then i have to diaplay to below format

   setNumColumns(3) 

   for example horizontal value is 2 and vertical value 2 then i have to diaplay to below format

   setNumColumns(2)

   for example horizontal value is 3 and vertical value 2 then i have to diaplay to below format

    setNumColumns(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one ...

```
       <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/myGrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_grid_fade"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        >
```